# Discord4j move user to another channel

Tags: java, discord, discord4j

I have users connected to the voice channel "waited" and I would like to move them to another channel. How to do it? Is it supported by discord4j?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [GuildMemberEditSpec](https://javadoc.io/static/com.discord4j/discord4j-core/3.0.10/discord4j/core/spec/GuildMemberEditSpec.html). There is a command `setNewVoiceChannel` that can be used to move the user to a new voice channel.